# Seed Silverstripe database

Tags: php, database, silverstripe

Is it possible to "seed" a database like you can in rails? I want to use a seed in combination with an imageobject manager so that I can get records by title.

Comment: You might want to take a look on the [silversmith](https://github.com/unclecheese/SilverSmith) project. Besides code scaffolding it has a [content seeding](https://github.com/unclecheese/SilverSmith#content-seeding) & [content population](https://github.com/unclecheese/SilverSmith#content-population) feature.

Comment: silversmith is outdated (wasn't ported to 3.1), but there is a seeder module out now which looks promising: https://github.com/Little-Giant/silverstripe-seeder .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your comment left on Ingo's answer, you want to add a `requireDefaultRecords()` method to your page class.

The below is from a recent project and ensures there is a particular user group, but you can do the same with any type of `DataObject` (e.g. `Page`).

```php
public function requireDefaultRecords() {

    // Make sure there is a readers security group
    $group = Group::get('Group')->filter('Code', 'readers')
    if ( !$group->exists() ) {
        $group = Group::create(array('Title' => 'Readers'));
        $group->write();
    }
}
```

This function is run on all `DataObject` classes when you do a build.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default values of your page `$db` variables by setting the `$defaults` array.

```
class Page extends SiteTree {

    public static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Text',
        'Description' => 'Text'
    );

    public static $defaults = array(
        'Title' => 'Default Title',
        'Description' => 'Default Description'
    );

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by "seed" in this context. There's a ["data-generator" module](https://github.com/lingo/silverstripe-data-generator) which writes random data with educated guesses on the ORM column types.

Comment: By "Seed" I mean that I want to add in default records. So when the database is built, it adds certain records in (ie Title: Banner 1, Link: "http://www.google.com")